# Nativescript webview on navigate

Tags: webview, nativescript, uiwebviewdelegate, angular2-nativescript

Is there a "navigate" event on webview in **nativescript**?

I've done it in **Xamarin (c#)** with

```
Browser.Navigating += Myfunction
```

Is there any event like this in nativescript? I would like to make it so that if i click on a link outside my scope of the website then i want the device to open a webpage of that url and not navigate inside of the webview.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your case correctly, however in my opinion you could use `HtmlView` to display `URL`. When you tap ot the link you will be redirected to the device Browser. `<HtmlView html="www.google.com" />`

Comment: That's not the case. I have a WebView and when i click on a link inside the webview i want to detect if the link is within the scope of my site in the webview or it's a external link, if it's a external link i want to open a new browser intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you could handle the `WebView` `loadStartedEvent`, and to verify the URL whether is in the scope of your site. If it is not, you could set new URL to the webview and you will be able to prevent the user to go in different web page. I am attaching sample code.

main-page.xml

```
<Page xmlns:RL="nativescript-ripple" xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="navigatingTo">
 <GridLayout>
     <WebView src="https://www.google.bg/" id="wv" />

 </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

main-page.ts

```
import { EventData } from 'data/observable';
import { Page } from 'ui/page';
import { HelloWorldModel } from './main-view-model';
import {StackLayout} from "ui/layouts/stack-layout";
import {WebView, LoadEventData} from "ui/web-view"

// Event handler for Page "navigatingTo" event attached in main-page.xml
export function navigatingTo(args: EventData) {

  let page = <Page>args.object;

  var webview:WebView = <WebView> page.getViewById("wv");
    webview.on(WebView.loadStartedEvent, function (args: LoadEventData) {

        let message;
        console.log("url "+args.url.substring(0, 21));
        console.log("eventName "+args.eventName);
        console.log("navigationType "+args.navigationType);
        if(args.url.substring(0, 21) !== "https://www.google.bg/"){
          (<WebView>args.object).url="https://www.google.bg/";
          console.log("returns back");
        }
    });
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

For people working on NativeScript-Vue I just did this :

```
<template>
  <Page actionBarHidden="true">
    <WebView :src="html" @loadStarted="onLoadStarted" />
  </Page>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    onLoadStarted (event) {
      console.log('navigation detected with destination :', event.url)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This way you can prevent navigation and do whatever you wants :)